# Создание проекта

Tags: xcode

Доброго дня! вопрос начинающего, учусь по учебнику написанному с примерами из xcode4

Когда создаешь проект в 4 версии, то там три флажка можно указать:

- use storyboard,
- use ARC,
- use unit test.

В xcode5 таких опций я не нашел- автоматически создается проект с использованием storyboard.
Вопрос: без сторибоарда теперь нельзя как в 4версии работать с xib-файлом?
примеры проектов в учебнике приводятся без сторибоардов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работать можно, но Apple рекомендует переходить на `storyboard'`ы, так как по их мнению это более прогрессивный метод работы с визуальными элементами. Тем не менее вы по прежнему можете создать новый проект со `storyboard'`ом (или создать пустой проект в котором его не будет по умолчанию) и добавить все необходимое Вам(например классы и ассоцииируемые с ними `.xib-`файлы). Главное понимать что в случае со сторибордами, что с `.xib`ами ничего нет "за сценой". Весь код который обрабатывает работу с визуальными представлениями уже расположен в Вашем проекте. Разницу можете сравнить в методе

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

который находится в `AppDelegate.m`. Там или получение значений со сториборда (в случае если проект использует его), либо инициализация соотвествующих `UIViewController'`ов(если используются `.xib'`ы). Более того Вы можете вообще не использовать визуальные представления а описать все кодом, что в некоторых ситуациях может быть единственным правильным выходом в ситуации. Посмотрите [это](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjcP79fDVyU) видео, может помочь Вам понять как все это работает

Comment: я Вас понял, с добавлением вручную xib-файлов тоже разобрался.
спасибо!