# Не могу разобраться со storyboards в Xcode 5

Tags: ios7, xcode, xib, uitableview

Всем привет, не могу разобраться со сторибордами. Гуглю уже третий день, делал по мануалам – ничего не получается. Почти все мануалы по xcode 4.x, а я работаю в пятом. Я как понял, есть какая-то разница в реализации между xcode 4 и 5. Не запускаются даже самые простые схемы, не могу понять вообще принцип сторибордов (в целом понятно, но как нужно что-то реализовать – ступор), поэтому и не понимаю, почему ничего не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, понять разницу между xib и storyboard. В чем лучше работать и при каких раскладах? Все книги по IOS 6, которые у меня есть – все с примерами xib, которые я даже не могу запустить в 5-ом xcode. У apple адекватной документации не нашел, все запутанно. По xcode 5 + IOS 7 книги, как я понимаю, еще не скоро выйдут, пару месяцев наверное ждать. Нужно реализовать примерно такую схему, ячейки в таблицах – статические.

Схема:

[image: img]

Answer (score 3):

Рекомендую изучить работу с xib. Довольно хорошо описано с примерами в книге: "[**Программирование под iOS. Для профессионалов**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785446101023&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0)".

Почему xib, а не storyboard, опять же выдержка из этой книги:

[image: img]

Comment: Спасибо, а книга у вас эта есть в электронном виде или это просто сфотканная страница? Я как понял, это одна из самых адекватных книг по этой теме, надо ждать только, пока новые выйдут.

Comment: это фото страницы с бумажной книги. в электрическом виде не нашел. книга адекватная и стоит своих денег.

Answer (score 3):

По порядку:

- сториборды везде функционально одинаковые
- разница между 4 и 5 версией Xcode есть, в целом улучшена функциональность и внешний дизайн. В остальном почти все в наличии в одинаковом комплекте
- xib'ы удобнее, сториборды проще, [уже обсуждали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/258614/xcode-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0). Навигация и функционал таблиц например реализовывается чуть по разному. Для сторибордов можно скачать и посмотреть [раздел семь](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3973306), там уже Вам будет более понятно как это работает. С xib'ами в сети так же много примеров. Чуть больше кода, но более понятна логика реализации. Также можно писать все вообще без визуальных представлений, все кодом (иногда без этого никак)
- у Apple в документации ничего не запутано, бейте в гугле все вопросы, ответы найдете гарантированно. Там и описания и разъяснения с картинками, примеры кода и готовые проекты с тестовыми реализациями
- в  Xcode 5 .xib'ы припрятали как опцию по умолчанию при создании проекта, тем не менее их тоже можно использовать. Гуглите `add UIViewController`

Comment: И какие-то специальные книги ждать не нужно. Хилегасс действительно молодец, но в сети это все уже тысячи раз пережевано в виде фото-видео-подкастов-статей