# Программирование под IOS без интерфейс билдера?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Я начал недавно изучать программирование под ios в xcode. И вот какая проблема. В книгах и сайтах почти всегда обьяснения через интерфейс билдер(стори борды , ксибы).  А вот чтоб все было описано программно, так не любят люди почему-то. Может кто-нибудь может посоветовать книги  или сайты с туториалами, в которых можно узнать как сделать например UITableview или viewcontroller без IB?

Comment: Разрешите поинтересоваться, зачем программировать без IB? 

Сегоднешнее программирование оно не то, что было раньше, когда нужно было абсолютно всё создавать с чистого листа. Вы пытаетесь создать "велосипед" который уже создан другими людьми, видь чем меньше времени/сил у вас уйдёт на один проект, тем больше времени/сил останется на другой. Либо я чего-то не понимаю. Это всего лишь моё мнение, не принимайте его как "близко".

Comment: я тоже считаю что если есть возможность облегчить себе жизнь, то как бы не стоит и заморачиватся. Сториборды очень облегчают жизнь

Comment: Позже конечно я собираюсь перейти на IB для экономии времени. Но пока хотелось бы разобраться как все устроено,чтобы более глубоко разбираться в среде.

Comment: @Dexter384, Уверен это будет очень хорошая практика.

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите проект UITableViewController [вот здесь](https://github.com/stanislaw/iOSExamples). Если вдруг с Гитхабом работать не умеете - вот [ссылка на zip](https://github.com/stanislaw/iOSExamples/archive/master.zip).

Это пример проекта, в котором вообще нет MainStoryboard и соответственно Interface builder'а, всё делается програмно.

Answer (score 2):

уже овечал недавно на аналогичный вопрос тут [Не могу разобраться со storyboards в Xcode 5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/259867/view-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-storyboards-%D0%B2-xcode-5?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=259874#259874)

Comment: Довольно хорошо описано с примерами в книге: 'Программирование под iOS. Для профессионалов' https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19462325/

Comment: Вот только отсутствие в книге упомянания UICollectionView говорит о том что она описывает iOS 5.0 (что не раньше видно из использования StoryBoard), а в 6.0 и особенно в 7.0 сильно перетряхнули интерфейс, об этом важно помнить при использовании